# how to check the return value of a function in unit test with OCMock 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I am using [OCMock 3](http://ocmock.org/reference/) to do unit testing in my iOS project.

OCMock is said a great unit testing library for iOS, but the OCMock document I linked above doesn't say clearly how to check the return value of a function, it all the time says how to stub function return & verify that. **But I don't want to stub that function return, I need to check the real return value.**

For example, I want to unit test a function of my `School` class:

```
@implementation School
...
- (void) checkStudents {
  BOOL isOnVacation = [[Coordinator sharedInstance] checkCalendar];
  if (!isOnVacation) {
     takeLecture();
  }
}
@end
```

My test case:

```
- (void) testCheckStudents {
    // create a partially mocked 'Coordinator' instance
    id coordinatorMock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[Cooridnator sharedInstance]];

    // run the method under test
    [schoolToTest checkStudents];

    // I want to check not only '[[Coordinator sharedInstance] checkCalendar]' is invoked, but also check its return value is YES. How to check this in OCMock?
    OCMVerify([coordinatorMock checkCalendar]);
}
```

I don't want to stub the return value of `[[Coordinator sharedInstance] checkCalendar]`, but run the real implementation.

I want to check not only `[[Coordinator sharedInstance] checkCalendar]` is invoked, but also check its return value is `YES`. How to check this in OCMock?

(With its documentation, I can only see stub function return here & there then verify the function is called. Do I miss something in its documentation?)

Answer (score 3):

Verifying the return value of `[[Coordinator sharedInstance] checkCalendar]` is not within the scope of this case because your unit test is validating the behavior of `School`. The idea behind mocking objects is to be able to make the assumption that objects other than the one you are testing depends on are behaving as expected.

Your test in its current state is perfect - you are verifying simply that `checkCalendar` is invoked when `checkStudents` is called under default conditions, under the assumption that `Coordinator` is behaving exactly as expected.

If you want to verify the return value of `checkCalendar`, you should write a separate test method in `CoordinatorTests` testing its return value under various conditions:

```
// CalendarTests.m

- (void) testCheckCalendar
{
    // Do some setup to mock the conditions created by checkStudents

.
.    
.

    // Verify
    XCTAssertEqual([[Cooridnator sharedInstance] checkStudents], YES);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. You should write one test for `checkStudents`. This is the one you have. You should write a separate test for `checkCalendar`, and for that test you probably don't need OCMock at all; just call the method and make assertions on the return value.